# java process consumes more memory over time but no memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

my java service is running on a 16 GB RAM host with -Xms and -Xmx set to 8GB.
The host is running a few other processes.

I noticed that my service consuming more memory over time.
I ran this command `ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n` on the host and recorded the memory usage by my java service.

When the service started, it used about 8GB memory (as -Xms and -Xmx set to 8GB) but after a week, it used about 9GB+ memory. It consumed about 100MB more memory per day.

I took a heap dump. I restarted my service and took another heap dump. I compared those two dumps but there were not much difference in the heap usage. The dump shows that the service used about 1.3GB before restart and used about 1.1 GB after restart.

From the process memory usage, my service is consuming more memory over time but that's not reported in the heap dump. How do I identify the increase in the memory usage in my service?

I set the -Xms and -Xmx to 8GB. Host has 16GB RAM. Do I set the min/max heap too high (50% of the total memory on the host)? would that cause any issues?

Answer (score 3):

OK so you have told the JVM that it can use up to 8GB for the heap, and you are observing a *total* memory usage increasing from 1.1GB to 1.3GB.  That's not actually an indication or problem *per se*.  Certainly, the JVM is not using anywhere like as much memory as you have said it can do.

The second thing to note is that it is unclear *how* you are measuring memory usage.  You should be aware that a JVM uses a lot of memory that is NOT Java heap memory.  This includes:

- The memory used by the `java` executable itself.
- Memory used to hold native libraries.
- Memory used to hold bytecodes and JIT compiled native code (in "metaspace")
- Thread stacks
- Off-heap memory allocations requested by (typically) native code.
- Memory mapped files and shared memory segments.

Some of this usage is reported (if you use the right tools).

The third thing is that the actually memory used by the Java heap can vary a lot.  The GC typically works by copying live objects from one "space" to another, so it needs a fair amount of free space to do this.  Then once it has finished a run the GC looks at how much space is (now) free as a ratio with the space used.  If that ratio is too small, it requests more memory from the OS.  As a consequence, there can be substantial step increases in total memory usage even though the actual usage (in non-garbage objects) is only increasing gradually.   This is quite likely for a JVM that has only started recently, due to various "warmup" effects.

Finally, the evidence you have presented does not say (to me!) that there is no memory leak.  I think you need to take the heap dumps further apart.  I would suggest taking one dump 2 hours after startup, and the second one 2 or more hours later.  That would give you enough "leakage" to show up in a comparison of dumps.

> From the process memory usage, my service is consuming more memory over time but that's not reported in the heap dump. How do I identify the increase in the memory usage in my service?

I don't think you need to do that.  I think that the increase from 1.1GB to 1.3GB in *overall* memory usage is a red herring.

Instead, I think you should focus on the memory leak that the *other evidence* is pointing to.  See my suggestion above.

> Do I set the min/max heap too high (50% of the total memory on the host)? would that cause any issues?

Well ... a larger heap is going to have more pronounced performance degradation when the heap gets full.  The flipside is that a larger heap means that it will take longer to fill up ... assuming that you have a memory leak ... which means it could take longer to diagnose the problem, or be sure that you have fixed it.

But the flipside of the flipside is that this might not be a memory leak at all.  It could also be your application or a 3rd-party library caching things.  A properly implemented cache could use a lot of memory, but if the heap gets too close to full, it should respond by breaking links<sup>1</sup> and evicting cached data.  Hence, not a memory leak ... hypothetically.

---

<sup>1 - Or if you use `SoftReference`s, the GC will break them for you.</sup>